# Replace Text Between 2 Characters in Vim

Tags: shell, vim, sed

I am working on a Legacy Code, where I am having statements like:

```
int array[MAX_SIZE_FOR_THIS_ARRAY];
```

In VIM, I want to replace the Text between [ & ] (including [ & ]) with *ARRAY* as follows:

```
int array_ARRAY_;
```

Please NOTE:
1. The Array Size Macro will be different for Different Arrays, hence we cannot use MAX_SIZE_FOR_THIS_ARRAY in our search pattern.
2. The name of variable "array" is also not fixed.

I need to search for [ ] only & replace [...] with *ARRAY* everywhere, in thousands of lines of code.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ca[` would be the answer if you are doing it with vim.

since you tagged the question with `sed` too, here is the way with sed:

```
kent$  echo "int array[MAX_SIZE_FOR_THIS_ARRAY];"|sed 's/\[[^]]*\]/_ARRAY_/'
int array_ARRAY_;
```

with your example,

```
sed 's/\[.*]/_ARRAY_/'
```

this works too.

Comment: Thanks. MAX_SIZE_FOR_THIS_ARRAY was just an example quote. The macro names may be different for each array.

Comment: @SandeepSingh, the second example should get everything from `[` to the last `]` on each line.

Answer (score 9):

While the cursor is anywhere inside the square brackets, you can use:

<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>`_ARRAY_`

To help you remember:

- <kbd>c</kbd> change
- <kbd>a</kbd> around
- <kbd>[</kbd> square brackets
- `_ARRAY_` with `_ARRAY_`

Comment: +1, didn't knew there was anything like `change around` in vim. How do you search that in help? (Not getting by plain `:h ca`)

Comment: :h text-objects @mohit

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way with which I can do it in one go -- for all the places in the File, without bringing the cursor to each array

Comment: @SandeepSingh, sure, see [jh314's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18080330/732284). You can adapt it to your situation.

Answer (score 4):

You can do a substitution:

```
:%s/array\[MAX_SIZE_FOR_THIS_ARRAY\]/array_ARRAY_/g
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. But the Macro Name: MAX_SIZE_FOR_THIS_ARRAY is NOT the same everywhere. Every array may have different size & different macro associated with it. Can you please suggest something irrespective of the exact pattern b/w [ & ].

Comment: @SandeepSingh, use `.*` instead of `MAX_SIZE_FOR_THIS_ARRAY` if you want to get everything between the brackets, and remove `array` from both the left and the right part of the expression if you want to do this for every instance where brackets appear, whether or not they have `array` in front of them.

Comment: @rid You would probably want to use `.\{-}` in that case, the lazy version of `.*`. Otherwise, `array[0][1]` will be replaced with `array_ARRAY_`, not `array_ARRAY_[1]`.